# Derivative using Power Rule, my answer doesn’t match textbook

Tags: derivatives

I’ve been working through problems in an old calculus book, trying to learn derivatives. Here’s a problem I’m stuck on:

Find dy/dx of $y=(1-x)(1+x^2)^{-1}$

And here’s the answer in the back of the book:

$(x^2-2x-1)(1+x^2)^{-1}$

What I get is close:

$(x^2-2x-1)(1+x^2)^{-2}$

It seems like a pretty straightforward use of the Product Rule. I suspect it’s my basic algebra skills that are letting me down. Here’s how I approach it:

dy/dx of (1-x) is -1

dy/dx of $(1+x^2)^{-1} is -2x(1+x^2)^{-2}$

Therefore:

$y’ = (1-x)(-2x(1+x^{2})^{-2}) - (1+x^{2})^{-1}$
    $= (-2x(1+x^2)^{-2}) + (2x^2(1+x^2)^{-2}) - (1+x^2)^{-1}$
    $= (2x^2 - 2x)/(1+x^2)^2 - 1/(1+x^2)$
    $= ((2x^2-2x-1) - (1+x^2))/(1+x^2)^2$
    $= (x^2-2x-1)/(1+x^2)^2$
    $= (x^2-2x-1)(1+x^2)^{-2}$

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The "answers in the back of the book" are often wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I obtain the same answer as you, by two different ways.

Answer (score 1):

It is by the product and chain rule
$$y'=-(1+x^2)^{-1}+(1-x)(-1)(1+x^2)^{-2}2x$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought maybe the book’s answer was wrong but that seemed like taking the easy way out.